# owl-carousel stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Yesterday i added jquery owl-carousel to my site. It worked perfectly. Today it somehow stopped working and i cant make it work. The mark up for html is

```
 <div class="vyrobky">

<div class="vyrobky_holder">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>
    <div class="item"> <a href="zabradlia/5.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" ></a></div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

i am loading this with ajax. I also add

```
<script class="delete_script" src="owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

to the site and have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

on the site , ( i am using lightbox and faterlight too )

i am executing

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        980:{
            items:1,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        },
        1440:{
             items:3,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
        1600:{
             items:3,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }


    }
})
```

in the owl-carousel.min.js so its get executed when the script is added to site.
Why did this stop working suddenly?

Also when i inspect site why anythins isnt showping up , the html is there and owl-carousel has `display:none`but thats all , when i set display to block or remove display none , it shows html without styling e.g like i didnt have owl-carousel cs or js file included. The navigators e.g owl-next/prev are not even there.

Comment: check your brower console any errors

Comment: or when the page is loaded try this from the browser console `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        980:{
            items:1,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        },
        1440:{
             items:3,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
        1600:{
             items:3,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }


    }
})`

Comment: when i execute the code in console for the 1st time . it throws 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function(…) , the second time it works. no other errors in console

Comment: ok when you did it for second time did the carousel start to wrk?

Comment: nope. I figureed it out. I included the lastes jquery... weird, yesterday it worked with jquery i originali included.